# Sort answers by oldest

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, answers

Maybe I am going senile, but I had answers sorted by "oldest" and now it says "newest". Was this ever an option, or did I just dream it one night?

Comment: You probably want to request this on the [SO Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), for now you can go to the last page to see the oldest items.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71561/bring-back-the-oldest-sort-order-for-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the "oldest" option was changed to "active".  There has been some complaint about this.  Try MSO if you want to complain too.

Comment: Corrected post. "Newest" always existed.

Comment: @ChrisF: Thanks.  I really appreciate your taking the time to help and correct me.  Both here *and* on webapps.  :-)

Comment: I didn't realise that.